# Using achemso class - need not-default italicized "et al" in references for ACS Nano submission

Tags: achemso

I'm using the `achemso` **class** to submit a paper to ACS nano and I need "et al" in my references to be italicized.  I'm using bibtex.

I've tried going into my Miktex bst folder and changing the achemso.bst file such that all instances of "et~al" are replaced by `\emph{et~al}` but that didn't fix it.

Since the class automatically sets the `\bibliography` style, I'm not actually sure which file is being used to format the bibliography so maybe I'm changing the wrong one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[journal = ancac3,manuscript = article]{achemso}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Nevermind!

Found the issue: I just had to move my base .tex and .bib files to a new folder and recompile (not recompiling and replacing all the other generated files like .aux and .bbl and stuff which were in the original folder).

Editing the achemso.bst file and replacing et~al with \emph{et~al} works fine!

Answer (score 4):

After checking with the ACS, I find that *ACS Nano* is (currently) unique in the family of ACS publications in using italic for 'et al.', 'etc.' and so on.  I have therefore extended `achemso` to cover this situation. As of v3.8, the correct (italic) formatting will be applied to 'et al.' in the bibliography with the `ancac3` journal style.